# Serverless Typescript plugin packs all my lambda functions into one zip archive

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless

Below is my serverless.yml

```
service: serverless-typescript-example
provider:
  name: aws

package:
  individually: true

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript

functions: 
  hello1:
    handler: hello1/src/index.handler
  hello2:
    handler: hello/src/index.handler
```

and my folder structure looks like below

```
hello1
 --index.ts
 --package.json
hello2
 --index.ts
 --package.json
package.json
serverless.yml
```

when I run sls package it creates 2 zip archives in .serverless folder with names hello1.zip and hello2.zip. Upon unzipping both folders have identitical contents i.e hello1 ande hello2 with node_modules.

Is there any option to resolve this and can we place the .zip file in the respective function folder ,i mean hello1.zip in hello1 and hello2.zip in hello2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i haven't used the `serverless-plugin-typescript`, but we use `serverless-webpack` and it does a pretty neat job. It reduced the lambda size a lot since it uses webpack to bundle.

there is also a serverless create template that uses the `serverless-webpack` plugin.

```
serverless create --template aws-nodejs-typescript
```

the zip files are placed by default in the `.serverless` folder. You can use the command below specify a destination folder. I don't think there is a way to define different destinations for each entry point.

`serverless package --package my-artifacts`

Comment: Thanks @Arun K.Do you have a single parent serverless.yml file which packages all the functions or multiple serverless.yml for each function.

Comment: One serverless.yml file and I package the functions as independent zip files

Comment: even I have the same structure but some how every zip file has all the functions inside it

Comment: Try separating the handler functions to different files